# Using machine-learning techniques for data-dependent operations in ciphers

Tags: cryptanalysis, symmetric, statistical-test

From 'Methods of Symmetric Cryptanalysis' by Dmitry Khovratovich,

> The data-dependent operations are one of the most controversial design concepts. We say that an operation is data-dependent, if it is expressed as a family of functions indexed by input data. The examples are key-dependent S-boxes, key- and message-dependent rotations and
>   permutations. The advantage of data-dependent operations is that its statistical and diffusion properties are largely unknown to the attacker, so that she can not predict the behaviour of the primitive on a large set of data.
>   On the other hand, the advantage quite often converts to the disadvantage. Indeed,
>   if the statistical property is key-dependent, then by statistical parameters of a sample yield
>   information about the key. The main difficulty of the analysis is hence the extraction of those
>   properties and relating them to a particular key group...

Can we use maching learning techniques for cryptanalysis of these operations?

Comment: Yes There are few papers using genetic algorithms but i would be very curious to know others

Comment: @sashank: May I know which are the papers?

Comment: there are plenty , just search for "cryptanalysis genetic algorithms" on scholar.google.com